# List of type DataROW to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a list as below:

```
List<datarow> list =  getxml_table.AsEnumberable().ToList();
```

This contains XML DATA in each row. How do I copy this to XML file ? I tried using a XML serializer but it requires a parameterless constructor, so that's not possible.

Any other Ideas.

***EDIT:***

XML data inside the `List<datarow>` (this is just a sample for illustration purposes, actual data is quite huge). Each row contains the following XML.

```
<List>
<Listevent someelementdata ="false">
 <someelement>
  <moreelement morelementdata = "1234"/>
</someelement>
</Listevent>
</List>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
using (stringwriter stringwriter = new stringwriter (new stringbuilder()))
{
  xmlserializer xmlserializer = new xmlserializer(typeof(DataRow));
  xmlserializer.serialize(stringwriter, list);
  var string = stringwriter.string();
}
```

Comment: Hmm.... not quite clear what is your problem. Can you elaborate more and show some sample of data you're getting into list as well as sample of code how exactly you have tried to write it to file?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Did you try to read xml content of DataRow through DataRow.Item property and save it in file?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - `DataRow` itself does not contains data (at least if we're talking about standard ADO.NET `DataRow`). Data being stored in concrete "cell" of `DataRow` (something like `DataRow["column_name"]`).

Next - why do you need `XmlSerializer` at all? Maybe I still have not understood your problem completely - but for me it looks like you're having `List<DataRow>`, and in some cell of each row you're having some string containing xml data.

So you can just write these strings to file something like (pseudocode):

```
List<DataRow> list =  getxml_table.AsEnumberable().ToList();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\1.txt"))
{
    foreach(var row in list)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(row["column_name"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: with this method how do I add xml header and encryption. Do I manually do that.

Comment: You can prepend header in the same file with `writer.WriteLine(your_header)` before loop by datarows. I wouldn't bother about parsing and then serializing back xml in use-case like yours - what can be more simple than writing your existed xml data as strings to the file....